# How to Modulate Current without an Arduino

Tags: current, frequency

I am looking to turn current "on" and "off" extremely fast without the use of an Arduino. With an Arduino, I understand I would be able to do that in code. However is there another way of doing this?

The main reason for doing this is, I have an electromagnet. And I would like to modulate the frequency of the magnetic field. To do this, I would need to allow and block the current from passing through at a certain rate.

Note: I am still getting a hold of the correct terminology. Therefore, please excuse any concepts/terminology used incorrectly.

Comment: What do you mean by "extremely fast"? An electromagnet is a large inductor, and V=L*di/dt.  Therefore to change I quickly you need a large V.  Then you need circuitry to control the applied voltage and timing.  What's the source of the timing?  What duty cycle and frequency are you looking for? What's the inductance of your electromagnet?

Comment: What do you want the current waveform to be thru the inductor. More info = better answer.

Comment: @JohnD Thank you for the information. That was my question exactly, what would be the source of the timing when using a regular circuit. As for the duty cycle and frequency, I am looking to see if it is possible generating any type of waveform with any cycle or frequency. My main goal is to be able to generate two or three different frequencies and be able to distinguish the frequencies from each other.

Comment: @Andyaka My apologies, this might be a simple question. Do you mean what frequency I would like my current waveform to be at?

Comment: @Ryan - my question is simple but I'll expand - what is the precise shape of the current waveform you wish to pass through the inductor.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to switch the current on and off at a certain rate, then you need an oscillator. A very common and cheap chip to do just that is the **555**. Its full name is the LM555, but you will probably find it called just the 555 (or the 7555, a newer CMOS version). Many oscillator circuits (astable multivibrators) can be found on-line. You can vary the frequency of the 555 oscillator with a variable resistor.

If you want to do it without a chip, you can buld an astable multivibrator with two transistors. Again, frequency can be set by resistor and capacitor values.

Comment: The hardest part isn't the oscillator but the current delivery system. Delivering an oscillating voltage across an inductor is a piece of cake but, delivering a defined current waveform (as implied on the question) can be significantly trickier.

Comment: Thanks for reply John and Andy, I will look into building an astable multivibrator.